# "command not found' while installing dependencies

Tags: altcoin, dependencies

While installing dependencies for compiling an altcoin wallet on VPS for run a Masternode - using Ubuntu 16 I run into this fatal error

```
In file included from alert.h:9:0,
                 from alert.cpp:5:
serialize.h:19:48: fatal error: boost/type_traits/is_fundamental.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
makefile.unix:200: recipe for target 'obj/alert.o' failed
```

whilst installing dependencies - the installation gets stuck on the last line - command not found

```
:~/Rupee-Core/src# libdb++-dev libboost-all-dev libcrypto++-dev libqrencode-dev libminiupnpc-dev
libdb++-dev: command not found
root@RUP2:~/Rupee-Core/src# libgmp-dev libgmp3-dev autoconf autogen automake libtool
```

does anybody have a suggestion what I could do to resolve this?

Comment: It almost looks as though boost is not installed and it's unable to continue compiling. Can you check that check it's installed using: sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev and retrying? If not, perhaps it is an incorrect version of boost? I also don't understand the Rupee-Core/src lines, are you trying to run those packages? Have you tried installing those packages instead, like apt-get installing libdb++-dev libboost-all-dev ... etc ? If you haven't done that, I would try that first.

Answer (score 2):

Not

```
libdb++-dev libboost-all-dev libcrypto++-dev libqrencode-dev libminiupnpc-dev
```

but

```
sudo apt-get install libdb++-dev libboost-all-dev libcrypto++-dev libqrencode-dev libminiupnpc-dev
```

Those are dependencies. `install` tells `apt-get` to download and install those dependencies. `sudo` gives `apt-get` admin permissions.